# What's the best equivalent for number(2, 4) from Oracle on the MS SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

On Oracle it is possible to create number datatypes that are "more precise" than what the number of digits conveys. So in the case of the `number(2, 4)` it's possible to store 0.0023. It is not possible to fill the first two decimal digits as in 0.12 or even 0.001. That would result in the error `ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column`

The SQL server does not allow a datatype `numeric(2, 4)`. The error is: `The scale (4) for column 'a' must be within the range 0 to 2.` Obviously I could create the table with a `numeric(4, 4)`.

The most precise number datatype on Oracle would be a `number(38, 127)`. The decimal digits 1 to 89 could not be filled, but from 90 to 127.
What would you do if to solve such a requirement on the SQL server?

Answer (score 3):

Could you use a CHECK constraint? Example:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD col DECIMAL(4,4) CHECK (ABS(col) < 0.01);
```